# Google Docs document format?

Tags: google-drive-api

What I'd like to accomplish: Download a Google Docs doc (with Google Drive API), modify it (for example highlight some text), then store it back to Google Drive (not messing up the format, so that it can be edited in the Google Docs app).

(Preemptive research:  I know that you can do some integration with Google's hosted AppScript, but I want to do this offline. I also know that a Google Docs doc can be exported to other formats, but I see no sign of reimporting in the Google Drive API.)

I'm not hopeful this can be done:
* The meta-data file (that you can get via the Google Drive API) lacks a "downloadUrl" attribute
* In offline mode, the data (stored in .../File System/) is binary and the Unix "file " command doesn't know what format it is.

Is this off-limits with the current Google Drive API?

Answer (score 0):

Your best (only) approach is to export the doc to a format that you can edit locally (html, docs, etc) and then reimport it. HTML is of course the easiest, but also the most lossy.